# Create, store and access files in Android storage?

Tags: android, permissions, storage, local-storage, adb

I am writing a file to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory + File.separator + "myFile.txt"` with the permission to write to the external storage. This seems to be successful (i.e.: no error messages in the logcat).

However, my issue is when I try to access the data folders or a folder which will contain the files I am making via adb shell or otherwise I am told permission denied. I realise this is because I am not root and the device is not rooted. However, is there a location on my Nexus 4 where I am able to freely create, store and access files easily without special permissions? If not is there a simple way to solve this issue?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I read the comments on @blackbelt answer and I can only imagine your code is wrong. Maybe if you show some code we can try to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` does not point to `/data` but to `/mnt/sdcard` or `/sdcard`. All in all you are looking in the wrong place

Comment: I still cannot seem to find the file that has been created in in either of those places. And Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() does in fact point to /storage/emulated/0/myFile.txt. But the /0/myFile.txt is not there.

Comment: all are the same physical location . What I posted are the more common  symlink to your sdcard

Comment: Okay, thanks I understand. In which case what other reasons could there be for my file not being there? If it weren't being written surely it would show an error?